# Android Studio can't see dagger 2 test component

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dagger-2

I` am trying to create some extra Dagger 2 modules for android instrumental tests. And Dagger 2 files are generated successfully, but my Android Studio IDE can't see it. I tried to use android-apt plug-in, gradle-apt-plagin and native android annotation processor. Nevertheless, nothing worked. However gradle 2 file for debug or prod application working fine.

For test module and component I use some custom sours folder:

```
def commonTestDir = 'src/commonTest/java'
    test {
        java.srcDir commonTestDir
    }
    androidTest {
        java.srcDir commonTestDir
    }
```

I use all of compile/apt, testCompile/testApt, androidTestCompile/androidTestApt for daggger 2 declaration in build.gradle file.

p.s. I`am sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Can anybody help me with my issue? Maybe i need to post some source of my project?

Comment: Please post the code including the build.gradle and thd directory structure